# traer id en un query con GET

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

lo que tengo es que un query quiero que me traiga unos campos dependiendo del id al que estoy ingresando

para eso estoy usando $_GET pero no me funciona , ya que la pagina me dice que no esta definida la variable $consulta

pero si quito la variable consulta y el id_registro le pongo uno manual si funciona pero lo que quiero es que con el $_GET me lo imprima automáticamente a tener que hacer manual con todos los registros que tengo. basicamente el error esta en esas 2 lineas , donde creo el $consulta y donde lo mando a llamar del query.

### datos.php

```
<?php
// Seteamos la cabecera a JSON
header('Content-Type: application/json');

// Configuramos la conexión a la base de datos
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
define('DB_USERNAME', 'root');
define('DB_PASSWORD', '');
define('DB_NAME', 'thanks');

// Desplegamos la conexión a la Basde de Datos
$mysqli = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);

$mysqli->query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");

if(!$mysqli){
    die("La Conexión ha fallado: " . $mysqli->error);
}

// Seleccionamos los datos de la tabla de act
$consulta = $_GET["id_registro"];
$query = sprintf("SELECT t1, t2, t3, t4, t5  FROM act WHERE id_registro = '".$consulta."'"); 


    //echo $id_registro;
   // $query = $link->query("SELECT t1, t2, t3, t4, t5, id_registro FROM act where id=?",[$id_registro]);

    $result = $mysqli->query($query);



// Hacemos un bucle con los datos obntenidos
$data = array();
foreach ($result as $row) {
    $data[] = $row;
}

// Limpiamos memoria consumida al extraer los datos
$result->close();

// Cerramos la conexión a la Base de Datos
$mysqli->close();

// Mostramos los datos en formato JSON
print json_encode($data);

//var_dump($data);
```

Comment: Estás usando mal `sprintf`  aquí: `$query = sprintf("SELECT t1, t2, t3, t4, t5  FROM act WHERE id_registro = '".$consulta."'"); `, aparte de que no lo necesitas para esto, ¿por qué no una cadena simple: **`$query = "SELECT t1, t2, t3, t4, t5  FROM act WHERE id_registro ='$consulta')";`**  y, si `id_registro` es numérica, ponlo así simplemente: **`$query = "SELECT t1, t2, t3, t4, t5  FROM act WHERE id_registro = $consulta)";`**

Comment: Se me escapó un paréntesis. Si `id_registro` no es numérica, ponlo así: **`$query = "SELECT t1, t2, t3, t4, t5  FROM act WHERE id_registro = '$consulta'";`**, y si es numérica, no hacen falta las comillas simples: **`$query = "SELECT t1, t2, t3, t4, t5  FROM act WHERE id_registro = $consulta";`** Aunque deberías usar consultas preparadas para evitar *inyección SQL*. Pero ese es otro tema.

Comment: el error que me marca no es del query sino de arriba, me marca "undefined array key id_registro" que es el que esta en $consulta = $_GET["id_registro"];

Comment: Revisa la respuesta. En el punto 2 me refiero al problema que comentas aquí. Cuando usas superglobales debes verificar que se está enviando un valor asociado con esa clave. Si es un formulario, debe haber un elemento cuyo `name` sea `id_registro` y si es por URL, debe haber algo como esto: `id_registro=1` o parecido. Si tienes *undefined index* es porque no envías una clave que se llame `id_registro` en los datos. Puedes usar `var_dump($_GET);` para verificar lo que se está enviando. En la respuesta he indicado cómo escribir un código totalmente controlado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hay varios errores en tu código:

1. Si usas un header con un tipo de contenido, toda la salida debe ser con ese tipo de contenido. No puedes poner json como tipo de contenido y usar `die` cuando haya errores. Esto no es coherente.
2. Controla siempre el contenido de las superglobales, porque el usuario puede no suministrar ese dato y tendrías un *Undefined index*.
3. No necesitas usar `sprintf` para esto. Con una variable simple bastaría (aunque te recomiendo usar consultas preparadas para blindar tu código).
4. Para leer resultados de mysqli debes usar alguno de sus métodos `fetch`

Vamos a corregir todo lo dicho:

```
<?php

  $data=array();
  // Verificamos en 1er lugar si se pasaron datos
  $consulta = !empty($_GET["id_registro"]) ? $_GET["id_registro"] : NULL;

  if ($consulta) {
    // Configuramos la conexión a la base de datos
    define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
    define('DB_USERNAME', 'root');
    define('DB_PASSWORD', '');
    define('DB_NAME', 'thanks');

    // Desplegamos la conexión a la Basde de Datos
    $mysqli = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);
    $mysqli->query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");

  if(!$mysqli){
      $data['error']="La Conexión ha fallado: " . $mysqli->error;
  } else {
      $query = "SELECT t1, t2, t3, t4, t5  FROM act WHERE id_registro = '$consulta'"; 
      if ( $result=$mysqli->query($query) ) {
          //Llenamos $data con cada fila
          while( $row = $result->fetch_assoc() ){ 
              $data[]=$row;
          }

          if (!$data) {
            $data['error']='0 filas encontradas';
          }
          // Limpiamos memoria consumida al extraer los datos
          $result->close();
      } else {
          $data['error']='Hubo un error en la consulta SQL';
      }
      // Cerramos la conexión a la Base de Datos
      $mysqli->close();
  }
      $data['error']='No se postearon datos';
  }

  // Seteamos la cabecera a JSON
  header('Content-Type: application/json');
  // Mostramos los datos en formato JSON
  echo json_encode($data);
```

Con este código obtendrás o los datos, o un json con una clave `error` indicando el motivo del error.

Comment: se podría decir que si funciono solo que ahora me marca en rojo en el  .js lo de data[0 ] en "for (const [index, [key, value]] of Object.entries(Object.entries(data[0]))) {
valores.push(value);
    labels.push(key);
   var datos ="   me dice que "Cannot convert undefined or null to object"

Comment: @GerardoMartínez Stackoverflow funciona por preguntas, si hay un nuevo problema es mejor abrir una nueva pregunta indicando en este caso el código JavaScript que estás usando para leer los datos.

Comment: va que va , deja abro una nueva pero primero voy a checar que hay en internet y docs.